# Bouncing all gets magnitude and velocity 0 after a while and stops

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, bounce

Im trying to simply get a ball to bounce with constant speed and without any infinite bounces. To avoid infinite bouncing I have added some drifting on each bounce in the collision event like this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Vector2 veclocityTweak = new Vector2(Random.Range(0f, 0.2f), Random.Range(0f, 0.2f));
    rigigidBody2D.velocity += veclocityTweak;
}
```

I have also rotated the colliders (the ball is bouncing within this box)
[image]

This works ok. not perfect. But my real problem is that the ball suddenly stops and the rigidBody2D.velocity sets to (0.0, 0.0) as well as the magnitude.

I tried to prevent this by this function running in the update function checking the velocity. The idea is that it should prevent the ball to go to 0 in velocity but still that happens after a while:

```
private void checkVelocity()
{
     Vector2 vel = rigigidBody2D.velocity;

     float minSpeed = 0.8f;
     if (vel.magnitude < minSpeed)
     {
         float multipl = Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f);
         rigigidBody2D.velocity = vel.normalized * multipl;
     }
}
```

Here is my settings in the Project Settings:
[image]

And I have set the material for the ball to:
[image]

How can I prevent the ball from stopping?

Comment: Does the bouncing work without any code?

Comment: it bounces but stops after a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend doing this:

```
float minVelocity = 10;
float maxTurn = 10;

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
{
    Quaternion randomRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(-maxTurn, maxTurn));
    rb.velocity = randomRotation * (rb.velocity.normalized * minVelocity);
}
```

This code will set the velocity of the ball to its previous velocity, but with a magnitude of `minVelocity`. It will also rotate that vector a random amount of degrees to make it bounce in different directions.